# How to run stored procedure from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am inserting some values in my table and at the same time, i want to call stored procedure that does some updates but i am having some issues with the syntax.  I have searched online but could not find anything. I am just trying to figure out how can to use the same connection.  here is my code:

```
sqlcmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MyTable(ID, Name ) VALUES(@ID, @Name)";
sqlcmd.Parameters.Clear();
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ID;
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Name;

sqlcmd.Connection = sqlcon;


sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

i saw some example on the internet but was not able to figure out how to use the same connection.
here is the example i found:

```
SqlCommand myCMD = new SqlCommand("sp_Test", sqlcon);
myCMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Comment: Have a look at the following example found here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1837318.aspx/1

Comment: What's the error or problem then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code for executing procedure is like as follows

```
using( SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connenctionstring))
{
 using(SqlCommand myCMD = new SqlCommand("sp_Test", con))
 {
  myCMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  con.Open();
  myCMD.ExecuteNonQuery();//as its insert command
  con.Close();
 }
}
```

**Must use Using which dispose as well as close connection**